# Nonequilibrium green function for interacting systems

Tags: interactions, greens-functions, non-equilibrium, self-energy, quantum-transport

In [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-24088-6) by Ryndyk on quantum transport, p. 89, the retarded single-particle nonequilibrium Green function for a non-interacting nanosystem coupled to semi-infinite reservoirs of non-interacting electrons is given by

$$G_C^R(E)=[E-H_C-\Sigma^R]^{-1},$$

where $H_C$ is the Hamiltonian of the nanosystem and $\Sigma^R = \Sigma^R_L+\Sigma_R^R$ is the retarded self-energy due to coupling to the reservoirs (there are two of them, one attached "left" and one "right" to the nanosystem). Here, it is assumed that the system-lead coupling is of the form $H_{C-\mathrm{lead}}=\sum_{i}V_i d_i^\dagger c + \mathrm{h.c.}$ where $d_i^{(\dagger)}$ are the reservoir and $c^{(\dagger)}$ the system operators.
This equation for $G_C^R$ above follows directly from the Dyson series since $\Sigma^R$ is known exactly (for example, in the wide band approximation, it is constant and proportional to the system-lead line width function $\Gamma$).

My questions now are that:

- Does this result also hold true for interacting $H_C$ (meaning, $H_C$ does not only consist of terms bilinear in fermionic creation and annihilation operators), thus leading for an exact expression of the many-body nonequilibrium Greens function?
- To be more concrete: Suppose, $H_C$ is a Anderson-Holstein model
  $$H_C = \varepsilon c^\dagger c + \omega a^\dagger a + gc^\dagger c(a^\dagger + a)$$
  then I want $\Sigma^R$ to include only the interaction of the central nanosystem with the lead. The interaction between the electron and the phonon mode is contained in $H_C$, and I want to treat it "exactly" (meaning, not in a perturbation series, but in a truncated basis for numerical reasons). So the Hilbert-space of the central system is a direct product of the electronic and phonon sub-spaces $\mathcal{H}_C=\mathcal{H}_e\otimes \mathcal{H}_\mathrm{ph}$.
- The main problem I see is a proper definition of lead self-energy $\Sigma^R$ due to the coupling to the leads. In general, it is a energy-dependent function and does not include any operators, but only the system-lead couplings $V_i$ (or more precisely, the absolutes of them). For me it is not clear, how the representation of $\Sigma^R$ in the many-body Hilbert space of the central system should look like, since the system-lead coupling also includes fermionic reservoir operators (which I don't want to treat explicitly). In the single-particle case, the self-energy is defined as $\Sigma^R_{L,R}=VG^R_{L,R}V$ where $V$ is the matrix of system-lead couplings and $G_{L,R}^R=[E-H_{L,R}]^{-1}$ is the retarded GF of the isolated leads. Hence, it is related to single-particle quantities of the reservoir, like the surface density of states.